Remove posts that start with similar words (like a delete duplicate posts plugin)
Can anyone advise on a SQL query or plugin (or any other solution, as I haven't been able to find any) that can delete all posts that start with the same words, except the oldest of them? Or maybe to leave the post that has the longest title, while deleting the others? For example, if I have 3 posts:

Mobile phone 4GB some other words
Mobile phone 4GB different other words
Mobile phone 4GB whatever sentence

I would like to either:

delete the newest 2, whichever they might be, and keep only the first published post that starts with "Mobile phone 4GB".
or
delete the 2 posts with the shortest title, and keep only the one that has the longest title and starts with "Mobile phone 4GB" (regardless the publication date)

Any of the above will help in my case. The idea is to remove duplicate posts, and unfortunately I couldn't find a good plugin that can do this. All plugins that I've tried don't see the posts as different, because the title appears in the content as well, so posts are slightly different. Therefore, I think my only solution is to simply filter using the title's first words (3 in my example, maybe even 5).
Thank you.

nobody? I'm doomed
